# Simple form can't dismiss modal on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have simple form for where the user can leave a message and confirm his payment in one click...
Only the payment is confirmed and the modal doesn't close.
if I add the  `"data-dismiss" => "modal"` in my :submit the modal is closed but the payment isn't confirmed...
What I am missing ?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Payment confirmation</h4>
      </div>
      <%= simple_form_for(@booking, url: pay_booking_path(@booking), method: :patch, remote: true ) do |f| %>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4> Price :  <strong><%= @booking.max_booking_price %>$</strong></h4>
          <div class="motivations">
            <p>Why do you want to make this trip, tell us a bit about you</p>
            <%= f.input :motivation_message, label: false %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if I do it this way it close but payment doesn't work

```
 <div class="modal-footer" >
     <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary", "data-dismiss"="modal"%>
 </div>
```

### EDIT

I am also trying to fix it with some js but I am not comfortable yet with this: here's what I tried....

```
<script>
$('.btn').on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal').modal( 'hide' );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `data-dismiss="modal"` to match the id of the model i.e. `data-dismiss="myModal"`. Not tested.